# way to set the timing of sending the data in kinesis analytics for example every 5 mins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I am really confused about how kinesis and kinesis analytics work.

I need to send some data to kenisis analytic and then the top ten stories(data) should be sent to a lambda function every 5 minutes. 
I have Kinesis stream and also kinesis analytics set up as follows:

[image]

Now the problem is whenever data comes in to analytics, kinesis analytics send the  stories right a way to lambda and this is not what I want. I need to sent the data every 5 mins. Is there any way to set the timing of sending the data in kinesis analytics? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it:

```
FLOOR(("TRENDING_STORIES_001".ROWTIME - TIMESTAMP  '1970-01-01 00:00:00') SECOND / 40 TO SECOND)
```